# ESLint rule error for import

Tags: ecmascript-6, atom-editor, eslint

I am getting the below error by eslint.

I have added `ecmaFeatures: { "modules": true }` in the `.eslintrc` file as well.

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Because you're getting that message, it looks like you've upgraded to ESLint 2.0, which is great! I can see two changes that you'll make to your configuration, though if anything else comes up, it's probably covered under the [2.0 migration guide](http://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/migrating-to-2.0.0):

1. In 2.0, `"ecmaFeatures": { "modules": true }` has become `"parserOptions": { "sourceType": "module" }`.
2. We replaced [space-after-keywords](http://eslint.org/docs/rules/space-after-keywords) with a new rule, [keyword-spacing](http://eslint.org/docs/rules/keyword-spacing), which was introduced in one of the 2.0 betas. If you were using `"space-after-keywords: 2`, you can change that to `"keyword-spacing": 2` now.

Putting that all together, your `.eslintrc` for ESLint 2.0 should include something like this:

```
{
    "parserOptions": {
        "sourceType": "module"
    },
    "env": {
        "es6": true
    },
    "rules": {
        "keyword-spacing": 2
    }
}
```