# How should I update *.eslintrc* to ESLint see the changes?

Tags: javascript, spring-boot, eslint, project-reactor

I want to use ESLint on my JavaScript project. I use Project Reactor, Spring Boot, ReactJS and Webpack. I created *.eslintrc* file in the root folder near pom.xml.

It seems ESLint works. When I apply

```
eslint src\main\js\components
```

it says

`1:1  error  Parsing error: 'import' and 'export' may appear only with 'sourceType: module'`

Ok, I have found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35834879/eslint-rule-error-for-import) and updated my *.eslintrc*:

```
{
"env": {
    "browser": true,
    "commonjs": true,
    "node": true,
    "es6": true
},
"extends": "eslint:recommended",
"parserOptions": {
    "parserOptions": { "sourceType": "module" }
},
"plugins": [
    "react"
],
"rules": {
    "indent": [
        "error",
        "tab"
    ],
    "linebreak-style": [
        "error",
        "unix"
    ],
    "quotes": [
        "error",
        "double"
    ],
    "semi": [
        "error",
        "always"
    ],
    "import":"true",
    "keyword-spacing": 2
}
}
```

But that does not help.

I searched *.eslintrc* files in my project directory and found may *.eslintrc*, *.eslintrc.json*, *.eslintrc.yml* files, but they does not have *sourceType: module*. Seems they are generated by `npm install` command. One of them:

```
{
"rules": {
    "id-length": 0,
    "max-lines": 0,
    "max-statements-per-line": [2, { "max": 3 }],
    "max-nested-callbacks": [2, 3],
    "max-statements": 0,
    "no-implicit-coercion": [1],
    "no-invalid-this": [1]
}
}
```

I tried to rebuild the project, delete all *.eslintrc* except mine.

My *packages.json* contains:

```
"devDependencies": {
"babel-core": "^6.18.2",
"babel-loader": "^6.2.7",
"babel-polyfill": "^6.16.0",
"babel-preset-es2015": "^6.18.0",
"babel-preset-react": "^6.16.0",
"css-loader": "^0.26.4",
"eslint": "^5.0.0",
"eslint-plugin-react": "^7.10.0",
"extract-text-webpack-plugin": "^2.1.0",
"file-loader": "^1.1.10",
"image-webpack-loader": "^4.1.0",
"react-redux": "^5.0.7",
"style-loader": "^0.13.2",
"url-loader": "^0.6.2",
"webpack": "^2.2.1"
}
```

How should I update *.eslintrc* to ESLint see the changes?
Why additional eslint files are created?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to have nested `parserOptions` inside itself:

```
"parserOptions": {
    "parserOptions": { "sourceType": "module" }
},
```

Remove one level of nesting and it should work:

```
"parserOptions": {
    "sourceType": "module"
},
```

---

> Why additional eslint files are created?

Are they under `node_modules`? They’ll be from your dependencies. You shouldn’t need to worry about them.

Comment: That works. Yes, additional eslint files are under node_modules. Thank you a lot.